# php envio via curl nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, libcurl

Boa noite, estou a 2 dias tentando enviar dados do curl php para o nodejs
quando eu faço por fora do curl funciona...
mas precisava que fosse deste caminho....
tentativa 1 php:

```
    {
       $this->ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);


  curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  $result = curl_exec($this->ch);
 return curl_close($this->ch);
 }
```

tentativa 2:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 2403);   //<----- Commented out !
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(    //<--- Added this code block
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);
var_dump($data);
$data = curl_exec($ch)|
```

no nodejs  o metodo post de nenhum jeito traz algum tipo de retorno isso que eu já tentei um pouco de tudo e está me faltando ideias de como fazer ou o que estou fazendo errado kkk queria enviar via post um xml para o nodejs tratar mas nem um envio basico está indo então me sinto frustrado ... 4 dias no problema e mal estou engatinhando nele ...

```
  app.post('/teste', function (req, res,next) {

//   console.log(util.inspect(req));
//console.log(util.inspect(req, false, null, true /* enable colors */));;
console.log(req.params);
console.log(req.query);

  console.log('receiving data ...');
    console.log('body is ',req.body);
    res.send(req.body);


});
```

Este método eu consigo pegar os itens e os retornos estão ok:

```
app.get('/agencia2', function (req, res,next) {

//  console.log(req.params);
//  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.query);
  console.log(req.query.id);

   res.send("quase teste"); 
});
```

Comment: Porque tem que ser pelo curl? É curiosidade para saber se funciona ou tem um motivo específico?

Comment: como você iniciaria o processo de envio de informação do php ( codeinginter) para o nodejs? se tens alguma sugestao??

Comment: achei em um post do stack a minha pergunta.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048978/sending-messages-from-php-to-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no php consigo enviar tudo o que eu preciso e no nodejs eu processo o xml de retorno que não estava processando no php estou apresentando o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048978/sending-messages-from-php-to-node-js) que achei a resposta para meus questionamentos bem como o código correspondente.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/phpcallback', function(req, res) {
    var content = req.body;
    console.log('message received from php: ' + content.msg);
    //to-do: forward the message to the connected nodes.
    res.end('ok');
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
  var addr = http.address();
  console.log('app listening on ' + addr.address + ':' + addr.port);
});
```

curl no php:

```
<?php

$data = array("name" => "Robot", "msg" => "Hi guys, I'm a PHP bot !");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/phpcallback');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

echo curl_exec($ch)."\n";
curl_close($ch);

?>
```